# Existence of a set $A ∈M$ with each $m(A ∩ E_n) > 0$ and each $m(E_n \setminus A) > 0$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let ${E_n}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in a measure space $(X, M, m)$ with each $0<m(E_n) < ∞$. When is it generally possible to select a set $A ∈M$ with each $m(A ∩ E_n) > 0$ and each $m(E_n \setminus A) > 0$?

I have no idea how to approach the problem at all . A useful hint also would be great, thanks!

Comment: You want $m(A\cap{E_n}) > 0$ for all $n$ or at least one $n$?

Comment: @Salcio, a common $A$ for all $E_n$ obviously the exercise wants!

Comment: If one of the $E_{n}$'s is an atom, then we're out of luck. Similarly, if $E_{1} = F_{2} \cup F_{3}$, $E_{2} = F_{1} \cup F_{3}$, and $E_{3} = F_{1} \cup F_{2}$ for some atoms $F_{1}$, $F_{2}$, and $F_{3}$, then we're going to be unhappy. Heuristically, I think atoms will make our lives difficult.  

On the other hand, non-atomic measures satisfy an intermediate value property, so I'd guess that there's enough Cantor-like constructions to make such a set $A$ possible.  
That's my two cents so far. I can think about it more and come back with a real answer at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the definition of atoms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory))

So, given $(X,M,m)$ a measure space and $A\in M$, then $A$ is **not** an atom if $m(A)=0$ or if there is $B \in M$ such that $B \subseteq A$ and $0<m(B)<m(A)$. Note that in this case it is also immediate that $m(A \setminus  B) > 0$

Now let us consider:

> Let ${E_n}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in a measure space $(X, M, m)$ with each $0<m(E_n) <\infty$. When is it generally possible to select a set $A \in M$ with each $m(A \cap E_n) > 0$ and each $m(E_n \setminus A) > 0$?

Answer: when $E_n$ are disjoint sets and each $E_n$ is not an atom.

**Proof*: Since each $E_n$ is not an atom and $m(E_n) > 0$, we have that , for each $n$, there is $A_n\in M$ such that $A_n\subset E_n$ and
$$0<m(A_n)<m(E_n)$$
Let $A = \bigcup_n A_n$.

Since $E_n$ are disjoint, and $A_n\subset E_n$,  we have $A\cap E_n =A_n\cap E_n = A_n$ and
$E_n \setminus A = E_n \setminus A_n $.
So,

1. $m(A \cap E_n) = m(A_n) > 0$ and
2. $m(E_n \setminus A) = m(E_n \setminus A_n)>0$.

Comment: This isn't the complete answer on the subject; there are plenty of situations where sequences $E_{n}$ of overlapping sets will still admit such an $A$. For instance, $E_{n} = [-n, n]$ admits the set $A = (0, \infty)$.

Comment: @MichaelJesurum The question asks for "When is it generally possible ... " . The question does not ask for a necessary and sufficient condition.